# \ref and \cite stopped working

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, compiling, winedt

My WinEdt version had to be reinstalled and now I can't use PDFTexify or Texify. That wouldn't be a problem since I still can use PDFLaTeX. So I try that, what happens? Now, all `\cite{}` show `[?]` and `\ref{fig:}` and `\ref{tab:}` show `?`. And I dont even get a TOC!
Some example from `thesis.tex`:

```
\include{./preamble}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{./chapter1}
\include{./bibliography}
\end{document}
```

The preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,
    top    = 2.5cm,
    bottom = 2.5cm,
    left   = 2.5cm,
    right  =2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float, wrapfig, times, graphicx, amsmath, multirow,  sidecap,longtable,color, soul, threeparttable, mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
 \setlength{\textfloatsep}{0cm} \setlength{\floatsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0.4cm}
 \AtBeginDocument{%
\captionsenglish % Captions in english
\dateenglish     % Date format in english
}
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3mm}}
```

The `.bib` file:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{}
\end{thebibliography}
```

> chapter 1
>
> ```
> just text
> ```

The funny thing is, if I put the whole bibliography in the bottom of `thesis.tex`, the `\cite{}` works fine.

Btw. First of all, I would love to have `texify` work without any problems but if you don't know how to fix that, I'd still love it if you could help me with the referencing. Oh, and the TOC, too.

Comment: `pdflatex` needs at least two runs to get cross-references right. You probably need to set up the quick compilation configs to get the right number of runs (sorry, I'm not a windows user)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember, you have to run `pdflatex` *twice*, then `bibtex` (or `biber`), and then `pdflatex` at least one more time.

If the `texify` you refer to is `miktex-texify`, normally, `miktex` binary folder is in the path on a windows-machine. Therefore, you can run `texify` from the command-line.

Answer (score 2):

First of all with your code snippets we can't proof what is happening or not. We need a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). To include an short example of your used `bib` file please use package `filecontents` (`texdoc filecontents` for the manual) to include it in one MWE.

Do you use `bibtex` or `biber` for your bibliography? I assume `bibtex` for the following.

If you have problems with your editor first check whether you can compile your MWE from the command line. Change to the directory that contains your MWE, for example `c:\test\mwe.tex` and try `pdflatex mwe.tex`. This creates the `aux` file you need (proof it). Now use `bibtex mwe` (or `bibtex8 mwe`) to create the bibliography. Now run `pdflatex mwe` twice, better three times to create all cross references, the correct table of contents and the bibliography.

If this is compiling well, you have to configure your new editor WinEdt (version 7?) new. In this case please have a look into the manual.

If not, you have a problem with your TeX installation.

MiKTeX's `texify` runs `pdflatex` and `bibtex` (not `biber`!) as needed to get a final document. In WinEDT version 7 you can start this kind of compiling using `TeX`-> `TeXify`. If that does not work, try to uninstall WinEDT and install it new and give WinEDT a chance to recognize that MiKTeX is installed.  You can test if `texify` is working with `texify mwe` in your command line.

Comment: I see now that when I create a new file, everything seem to work. I guess the problem was that I pasted all the old .tex files in a different folder (backup). Then I erased all the files in the old folder (all, .aux, .bak etc). When I now moved them .tex files back, texify cant find any .aux files. But I dont understand why it doesnt create new ones? I have also tried copying the content of an old file into a new document, this works!(if I name the new file e.g. thesis2 instead of thesis). Then I just have to run texify and the .aux files are created (with wrong names, e.g. chapter1.2.aux)

Comment: Everything works fine again, thank u for your time though. I just had to compile the files using new names and then change back on both .tex and .aux. BTW I have never used bibtex, not deliberately. I have all my references in a .tex file that begins with \begin{thebibliography} \bibitem{name} Author. Title. Publisher.year.\\\bibitem{newname}...All problems began when I wanted to sort that bibliography, cause its tedious sorting by hand in the file